# How to contextualise reading Friere's Pedagogy of the Oppressed?

Tags: ethics, education, marxism

I've been asked to read *Pedagogy of the Oppressed* by Paulo Friere; I know very little about the subject of critical pedagogy. Which other texts should be read alongside it? Someone has suggested Fanon's *Wretched of the Earth*.

Comment: I might recommend Ilyich's *Tools for Conviviality* -- I'm not entirely sure why I've got them so closely connected in my mind, but the spirit/ethos of the works seem compatible

Comment: (Also Ranciere's *Ignorant Schoolmaster* seems like not the worst possible place to go here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fanon is a good suggestion, and his *Black Skins, White Masks* is also relevant to the topic.  You might also try Emile Durkheim and Ivan Illich (*Deschooling Society*).

For a less theoretical, more contemporary, more practical examination of the same issues, I suggest Kozol (*Savage Inequities*) or Gatto (*Dumbing Us Down*).